# How to change Nav Bar Controller Color for every VC based on user choice?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

In my app delegate I call the following code to set the color of the nav bar for every VC to be a blue. However, if the user does not log in and is just taking the app for a spin I want the Nav Bars to be a red.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 108.0/255.0, green: 158.0/255.0, blue: 236.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) // Blue

//    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 119.0/255.0, blue: 97.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0) // Red

UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
```

How would I go about changing the color based on a users choice for every VC?

Comment: check in your app delegate that user is logged in or not

Comment: call this in every VC `navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue`

Comment: please let me know if any issue

Comment: I think you mean "Nav Bar Controller Tint Color"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your color in every VC in `viewWillAppear` method like this

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 210/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
 }
```

if you are waiting for some event occur then you may change after completing it. like this

`navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 210/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)`

Comment: Thank you, I used NSUserDefaults with this to get what I needed

Comment: Hmmmm. Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following extension of `UIViewController` to your project, note this is the easiest and most straightforward way to 'run the same code on all view controllers' but it is using **method swizzling**. Whilst the code I have written below is perfectly safe if you don't know what you're doing it can lead to undesired/unexpected behaviour. **Proceed with caution.**

```
extension UIViewController {
    public override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        // make sure this isn't a subclass
        if self !== UIViewController.self {
            return
        }

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let originalSelector = Selector("viewWillAppear:")
            let swizzledSelector = Selector("extended_viewWillAppear:")

            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

            let didAddMethod = class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))

            if didAddMethod {
                class_replaceMethod(self, swizzledSelector, method_getImplementation(originalMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod))
            } else {
                method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
            }
        }
    }

    func extended_viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.extended_viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Call your code here that you want to run for all view controllers, table view controllers, tab view controllers etc...
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 210/255.0, blue: 255/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```